# How to use a substring in for loop of batch script?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, substring

This is my first batch script. I want to convert a list of files and use a substring of the input filename (Day of year). However the substring part doesn't work:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %G IN (%dirInp%%station%???0.DAT) DO (

SET filInp="%G"

SET doy=!filInp:~-9,3! rem this doesn't work?

rem Convert Trimble GPS receiver observations to RINEX
%dirExe%teqc -tr d %G > %dirOut%%station%!doy!0.%yy%D
)
```

So, how should I do this?

Comment: you should get an error message. For use in batchfile, use `%%G` instead of `%G`. `set filInp="%G"` should be `set "filInp=%%G"`

Comment: rem does not work in the middle of the string

Comment: Ok I changed the batch script using %%G it seems to work now. I actually tried that first, but there I think I used % instead of ! for the doy-variable. (And then I copied the code to the cmd-window earlier to see the error output and used %G, but forgot about that). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Stephan 's comment I've updated your code to make a minimal working example (MWE) using some abstact file paths and substring parameters.

Than I moved `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` inside the `FOR` loop and now it works for me on Windows 7.

I also closed `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` by `endlocal` (could be sensitive for further code excecution

```
@echo off

FOR %%G IN (C:\DirInput_StationA\201901.DAT C:\DirInput_StationB\201812.DAT) DO (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET "filInp=%%G"

    SET "doy=!filInp:~-10,4!"

    rem Convert Trimble GPS receiver observations to RINEX
    REM Changed your call to echo of the vars
    echo G: "%%G"; doy: "!doy!"
    endlocal
)
```